# Group by query in mysql and oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have created a table and trying to learn how to use group by query but its giving weird output.

```
create table student(bid char(3), sname varchar(15), totfee float, feepaid float,
  feebal float, branch char(3), city char(4));


insert into student values(101,'student1',16000,8000,8000,'mat','bang');
insert into student values(102,'student2',17000,8000,9000,'mar','bang');
insert into student values(103,'student3',16000,9000,7000,'btm','bang');
insert into student values(104,'student4',12000,8000,4000,'amr','hyde');
insert into student values(105,'student5',14000,6000,8000,'mat','bang');
insert into student values(106,'student6',18000,8000,10000,'mar','bang');
insert into student values(107,'student7',16000,4000,12000,'btm','bang');
insert into student values(108,'student8',11000,2000,9000,'amr','bang');
insert into student values(109,'student9',13000,5000,8000,'btm','bang');
insert into student values(110,'student10',16000,3000,13000,'amr','hyde');
```

Now I am trying to sort the students based on branch. For that I tried the following query

In Oracle

```
select * from student group by branch;
```

output

> Error- not a `group by` expression

In Mysql

output is :

```
  +------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+------+
  | bid  | sname     | totfee | feepaid | feebal | branch | city |
  +------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+------+
  | 104  | student4  |  12000 |    8000 |   4000 | amr    | hyde |
  | 103  | student3  |  16000 |    9000 |   7000 | btm    | bang |
  | 113  | student13 |  36000 |   18000 |  18000 | mal    | bang |
  | 102  | student2  |  17000 |    8000 |   9000 | mar    | bang |
  | 101  | student1  |  16000 |    8000 |   8000 | mat    | bang |
  +------+-----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+------+
```

Actually I was expecting every it to group all the students based on branch.. 
So how do I do that? and what is actually the use of group by query?
I even tried referring from website like w3school, and tpoint. But could not understand.

Comment: The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns

Comment: MySQL has a very sloppy implementation of the `group by` operator (not to say broken). See this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ for more details

Comment: For oracle you need to use aggregate function to use group by clause.

Comment: Thank you all.. 

Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. The links was excellent and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by only makes sense when used together with other aggregation functions like sum() or other.
These aggregation functions combine the values of several rows of a column. 
For example sum() calculates the sum of all values of the specified column. In your example these columns could be **totfee** or **feepaid**. But this calculates the sum of all rows, if you want the sum for every branch separately calculated you can use the group by clause on the branch column. Now your database calculates the aggregation functions over the rows that have the same **branch-value** and the result contains the same number of rows as there are distinct values for **branch** in your table.

Answer (score 2):

You can't select fields that are not aggregated and are not in `GROUP BY` clause.
Oracle is more strict about this rule in compare to MySQL. MySQL just takes first value, but Oracle throws an error.

Moreover `GROUP BY` is used to group records (aggregate). To sort results you should use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

'group by branch' will return all the different values for the 'branch' field. 
If you want to order the students based on the 'branch' field, you should use 'order by branch ASC' (or DESC).

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to **Sort**  the students based on branch, Instead of using an "group by", You can use "order by".

```
select * from student order by branch;
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use this query to get your final result:

```
with Tab AS (SELECT min(BID) AS ID FROM STUDENT GROUP BY BRANCH)
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE BID IN (SELECT ID FROM Tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you HAVE to  name each column which is used in the group by expression in the select statement and if you use * in your select statement ,you have to name all of your columns in group by expression:
select * from student  s
group by s.bid,s.sname,s.totfee,s.feepaid,s.feebal,s.branch,s.city
which is not a real grouping and above query equals to select * from student,and no grouping is really done.
you can have such queries in Oracle:

maximum totfee in each branch:

```
select s.branch,max(s.totfee) from student s group by s.branch
```

in this query oracle groups all of data according to their branches .
grouping based on branch means that you should have only 1 record for each branch like ‘amr’ in your output, normally you have 3 records for branch’amr’,thus you should  do some works to delete extra rows and you should tell oracle which rows should be deleted and which ones should be remained and it’s the reason of existence of max(s.totfee),with max function ,you say oracle to keep just the row  which has maximum totfee and delete other ones ,now you can have 1 output record for each branch .

Hint:If you wanna imply a condition you should use ‘having’ instead of where in above query.

number of branches which have more than 2 students:

```
select s.branch,count(*) from student  s group by s.branch having count(*)>2
```